# Find rows that are not equal/identical in two columns including NAs

Tags: r, na

I want to create a new dataframe in R that contains all the rows that do not have identical values in two given rows including those that are NA in one row and not in another.

So I want to subset this

```
person,opinion_1, opinion_2
a,agree,agree
b,disagree,agree
c,disagree,
d,disagree,
```

```
 df_example <- structure(
      list(
        person = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
        opinion_1 = c("agree",
                      "disagree", "disagree", "disagree"),
        opinion_2 = c("agree", "agree",
                      NA,NA)
      ),
      row.names = c(NA, -4L),
      class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
    )
```

into this

```
person,opinion_1, opinion_2
b,disagree,agree
c,disagree,
d,disagree,
```

I have tried using `x <- df[which(df$opinion_1 != df$opinion_2),]` but this only returns

```
person,opinion_1, opinion_2
b,disagree,agree
```

Is there a solution so that the subset will include mismatched NAs?

Comment: Try to use `is.na`

Comment: I don't just want to match `is.na` values though. I want to find matches to NA and non-NA values

Comment: I didn't meant that.  with `==`, the `NA` returns `NA` so you may have to do some extra step to make that NA as FALSE or TRUE

Answer (score 3):

We can do this using subsetting, the code below represents keep every row in which the opinion differs and additionally keep those rows that only have one opinion recorded:

```
dfn <- df[(df$opinion_1 != df$opinion_2) | is.na(df$opinion_1) | is.na(df$opinion_2),]
# results in:
  person opinion_1 opinion_2
2      b  disagree     agree
3      c  disagree      <NA>
4      d  disagree      <NA>
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text = "person opinion_1 opinion_2
a agree agree
b disagree agree
c disagree NA
d disagree NA", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

katie, this simple code solve your problem.

```
df = na.omit(df)
df = subset(df, df$opinion_1 != df$opinion_2)
```

The function `na.omit` delete the rows with NA values and the `subset` function returns the lines that opnion_1 and opinion_2 are different. If you don't want to use the `na.omit` function, this code also works:

```
df = subset(df, df$opinion_1 != df$opinion_2 & df$opinion_1 != is.na(df$opinion_1) & df$opinion_2 != is.na(df$opinion_2))
```